# Bundle database solution into standalone application

Tags: design-patterns, database

I'm building an OSX app that utilizes a Redis instance. It would be cumbersome to have the user install and boot a Redis server session only for the app to communicate with it. I'd imagine there are design patterns to handle these situations, regardless of the system (OSX, Android, etc) and database being used (MySQL, Mongo, etc).

What are good practices for bundling a database server into a standalone application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many programs include a copy of [SQLite](https://sqlite.org/), which is released as 'public domain', and can be linked into an executable. It reads and writes to a database stored as a single file on disk.

For example this is used to store bookmarks in Firefox.